# Convert DateTime into YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, datetime

I have a DateTime column  I need to add a new column using the DateTime column and convert into YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00 format.

**Example:**

```
DateTime
2021-06-01 11:32:00.000
2021-06-01 12:55:00.000
2021-06-01 00:32:40.000
```

**Expected Result**:

```
DateTime-------------------------------Converted--------------
2021-06-01 11:32:00.000----------------2021-06-01 11:00:00.000
2021-06-01 12:55:00.000----------------2021-06-01 12:00:00.000
2021-06-01 00:32:40.000----------------2021-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Why are you worrying about formats in the database? Format is a presentation layer issue, not a data issue. Format it where you display it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can also use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` for this**

```
SELECT
    DateTime,
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
      YEAR(DateTime),
      MONTH(DateTime),
      DAY(DateTime),
      DATEPART(hour, DateTime),
      0,
      0,
      0) AS Converted
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that this method also works with `datetime2` by using `DATETIME2FROMPARTS` and `datetimeoffset` with `DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS`, whereas the `DATEADD/DATEDIFF` trick in the other answer, while neat, does not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think John's now deleted answer using `FORMAT` would be even slower. Yours is probably faster, but only works on `datetime`, so I thought I'd put this here

Answer (score 2):

To truncate your datetime values to the floor of their current hour, you may use:

```sql
SELECT
    DateTime,
    DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, DateTime), 0) AS Converted
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo